# Nokogiri returns "no method error"

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I keep getting the same error in my program. I've written a method that takes some messy HTML and turns it into neater strings. This works fine on its own, however when I run the whole program I get the following error:

```
kamer.rb:9:in `normalise_instrumentation': undefined method `split' for #<Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet:0x007f92cb93bfb0> (NoMethodError)
```

I'd be really grateful for any info or advice on why this happens and how to stop it.

The code is here:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

def normalise_instrumentation(instrumentation)
    messy_array = instrumentation.split('.')
    normal_array = []
    messy_array.each do |section|
         if section =~ /\A\d+\z/
            normal_array << section
        end
end
return normal_array
end

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.cs.vu.nl/~rutger/vuko/nl/lijst_van_ooit/complete-solo.html'))
table = doc.css('table[summary=works] tr')

work_value = []
work_hash = {}

table.each do |row|
    piece = [row.css('td[1]'), row.css('td[2]'), row.css('td[3]')].map { |r|
        r.text.strip!
    }
    work_value = work_value.push(piece)
    work_key = normalise_instrumentation(row.css('td[3]'))
    work_hash[work_key] = work_value
end

puts work_hash
```

Comment: First, welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not necessary to apologize for learning. Just do your research, ask thoughtful, well-written questions, and we'll gladly help.

Comment: It really helps if you include a minimal example of the HTML you're encountering, and an example of what sort of data you want out of your code. Without that, we have to cobble up our guesses and play the mind-reader game, which we're not really good at. So, help us help you.

Comment: Thank you for your encouragement! And thanks for the tip on posting. Will be sure to do this in future. I am very grateful for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
row.css('td[3]')
```

Here's why:

```
row.css('td[3]').class
# => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet < Object
```

You're creating your `piece` array which then becomes an array of NodeSets, which is probably not what you want, because `text` against a NodeSet often returns a weird String of concatenated text from multiple nodes. You're not seeing that happen here because you're searching inside a row (`<tr>`) but if you were to look one level up, in the `<table>`, you'd have a cocked gun pointed at your foot.

Passing a NodeSet to your `normalise_instrumentation` method is a problem because NodeSet doesn't have a `split` method, which is the error you're seeing.

But, it gets worse before it gets better. `css`, like `search` and `xpath` returns a NodeSet, which is akin to an Array. Passing an array-like critter to the method will still result in confusion, because you really want just the Node found, not a set of Nodes. So I'd probably use:

```
row.at('td[3]')
```

which will return only the node.

At this point you probably want the `text` of that node, something like

```
row.at('td[3]').text
```

would make more sense because then the method would receive a String, which does have a `split` method.

However, it appears there are additional problems, because some of the cells you want don't exist, so you'll get nil values also.

This isn't one of my better answers, because I'm still trying to grok what you're doing. Providing us with a minimal example of the HTML you need to parse, and the output you want to capture, will help us fine-tune your code to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have been doing some further research into Nokogiri as I think this will help me understand what's going on. Each of the <tr> nodes in HTML look something like: 
`<TR>
 
<TD> P.D.Q. Bach (Peter Schickele)
 
<TD> Concerto piano vs orch
 
<TD> 2.2.2.2. 2.2.0.0. 1.0. str
 
<TD> pi
 
<TD> 25&rsquo;
 
<TD>
<TR>`

This is a catalogue of orchestral music, including instrumentation (the third <td>). I am aiming to create a hash where a simplified version of the instrumentation (normal_array) is the key and an array of the three original nodes is the value.

Comment: The end result will be that the user searches the keys for a match of the neat instrumentation and the program will return the musical work's name, composer and full instrumentation.

Comment: If the HTML looks like that, then it's malformed. Nokogiri will try to fix it, and may, or may not, succeed. You'll need to look to see what it does. Check the `errors` method for the doc returned after parsing to see.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error (undefined method) for a different reason, in my case it was due to an extra dot (put by mistake) like this:

```
      status = data.css.("status font-large").text
```

where it was fixed by removing the extra dot after the css as shown below

```
      status = data.css("status font-large").text
```

I hope this helps someone else